# Starting new activity with a gesture

Tags: android, android-activity, gesture, gestures

Ok. So I've been doing a bit of looking at gestures and such and am trying to find out how to set up my code so that when something like a left swipe happens I can open a new screen and same with a right swipe. Something like the calendar, where you can swipe through the days. I already have the gestures built. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I think I came up with something. I can't fully try it now but does it look right? Thanks.

```
public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
        ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = mLibrary.recognize(gesture);
        if (predictions.size() > 0 && predictions.get(0).score > 1.0) {
            String action = predictions.get(0).name;

            if ("left".equals(action)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Actinium.this, Radium.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();}
            else if  ("right".equals(action)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Actinium.this, Thorium.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();}

            }
        }
```

Comment: If you have additional information to add edit the original question, do not post it as an answer.  As to the content, I don't understand your question.  That looks just like the example code, I don't know why it wouldn't work.  Come back when you have tried it and have a specific question about what doesn't work.

Comment: Then why did you attempt to answer, seeing as your original comment had nothing to do with my question.

Answer (score -1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

See [documentation](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/gestures.html) for listening for gestures.

Comment: I've seen that. How do I tell like the left swipe to start that intent though? Like how does it tell the difference and which activity to start?

Comment: You should include the context in the intent. Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentClass.this,MyActivity.class);